# In R how to combine multiple string columns in an R dataframe into one list column

Tags: r

I’m trying to combine multiple string columns in a data frame into a single list with multiple elements.

Here is some sample data:

```
Df = 
Note1   Note2   Note3   OtherStuff
“do”    na  “re”    54
“fa”    “so”    “ti”    na
“mi”    “do”    na  10
```

What I want is:

```
DF = 
Note1   Note2   Note3   OtherStuff  Notes1_3
“do”    na  “re”    54      c(“do”, na, “re”)
“fa”    “so”    “ti”    na      c(“fa”, “so”, “ti”)
“mi”    “do”    na  10      c(“mi”, “do, na)
```

I tried the code below as suggested in another Stackoverflow Q&A:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(Notes1_3 = mapply(c, Note1, Note2, Note3)
```

This resulted in Notes1_3 equal to NULL for all the rows in the dataframe. This looks like something that should be easy to do and I’m just missing some detail.

Comment: Do you actually want it to look like that: with a string containing an R expression to generate that vector? Or is your goal for Notes1_3 to be a list column?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, it seems like the real goal is to search for strings in specific columns. There's a better way to do that. Given a dataframe "df" and a vector of strings to search for "search_strings":

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Note1 = c("do", "fa", "mi"), 
                     Note2 = c("na", "so", "do"),
                     Note3 = c("re", "ti", "na"),
                     OtherStuff = c("54", "na", "10")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
search_strings = c('do', 're')

df %>%
    mutate(Notes_YN = if_any(starts_with('Note'), ~ . %in% search_strings))

  Note1 Note2 Note3 OtherStuff Notes_YN
1    do    na    re         54     TRUE
2    fa    so    ti         na    FALSE
3    mi    do    na         10     TRUE
```

This function selects all columns starting with "Note" (see `?tidyselect::language` for more details on tidyverse selectors), runs the provided function (`x %in% search_strings`) and returns whether any of the columns return TRUE for that.

---

If you want `Notes1_3` to be a list column as in the title, you just need to make it into a list, not a vector:

```
df <- structure(list(Note1 = c("“do”", "“fa”", "“mi”"), 
    Note2 = c("na", "“so”", "“do”"), Note3 = c("“re”", 
    "“ti”", "na"), OtherStuff = c("54", "na", "10")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df
  Note1 Note2 Note3 OtherStuff
1  “do”    na  “re”         54
2  “fa”  “so”  “ti”         na
3  “mi”  “do”    na         10

df2 <- df %>%
    mutate(Notes1_3 = list(Note1, Note2, Note3))

df2
  Note1 Note2 Note3 OtherStuff         Notes1_3
1  “do”    na  “re”         54 “do”, “fa”, “mi”
2  “fa”  “so”  “ti”         na   na, “so”, “do”
3  “mi”  “do”    na         10   “re”, “ti”, na
```

If we look specifically at that column, we see it's actually a list of vectors as desired:

```
df2$Notes1_3
[[1]]
[1] "“do”" "“fa”" "“mi”"

[[2]]
[1] "na"   "“so”" "“do”"

[[3]]
[1] "“re”" "“ti”" "na"
```

Comment: I'm looking specifically for a column I can create for the following R code:  DF$Notes1_3_YN <- ifelse(DF$Notes1_3 %in% c("do", "ti"), 1, 0),   or c("fa", "so") or other possibilities

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're aim is. Are you looking to set this new column to 1 if a certain string or strings is found in that row's Notes1/2/3?

Comment: Exactly.  Actually, the original data are four columns with medication information.  I want to see if any of the four columns contain medications from different classes.  It's those classes that will be in a list to compare to the results of the mutate command.

Comment: What about the quotes around some of the strings? Are those just an artifact of copying text, or are they in the real data?

Comment: Those are just string data so I put the quotes to indicate that.  So, just an artifact of copying text I think.

Comment: @B.Koch I think I've solved your real question - see the edit

Comment: I think that did the trick!  Many thanks.  And, as an aside, I find there's always a better to code something than what I came up with.  To Infinity and Beyond! Cheers.

Comment: @B.Koch My pleasure. I learned a lot about the `across` functions trying to solve this

Comment: @B.Koch If this solved your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows so people know that this problem has been solved.